# Linux connecting to mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database-connectivity

I have been trying to connect to mysql all evening using PHP.
I know for a fact the username and password are correct as I have tried 3/4 and I know the permissions are set correctly in the database.

If I remote onto this machine and enter the exact same details into the commandline then i can connect to the database without issue.

The problem only seems to be with MYSQL and PHP.

A little more info:

I am trying to run a PHP app on the same server as the mysql database is on. The user has full grant permissions on the local machine. The error i am receiving is :

```
Fatal error: Attempt to connect to database kmc_cms on
```

The server is set so no remote access to mysql is available.

Comment: What exactly are you doing and what exact error do you get?

Comment: What error is mysql / php returning after doing a mysql_connect?

Comment: Can you connect remotely using the command line? Maybe you only have GRANTs on localhost.

Comment: I have updated the question with more information

Comment: Please give the complete error and the connect code. Perhaps you are able to connect to MySQL but not able to connect to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue. Within the mysql database config file there was an error which resulted in the connection allowing users from local host access only. Even though the PHP scripts were connecting using localhost it just would not authenticate. Hence I could log in using command line and not using PHP or other applications.

Answer (score 1):

In your question you don't show whether you're trying IP or localhost.

Do a

```
show grants for <username>;
```

and see if the connection you're trying is even allowed.

Comment: Appologies I am trying localhost, though I have also tried the ip of the server also

Comment: Which DB library? Sample code? Full text of the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled remote access for the user you're trying to connect with in mysql?